# Rails Iterate over collection in model's class method without reloading query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, class-method

I would like to iterate over a collection in a Model's class method.
Unfortunately, the only way seems to be using all :

```
def self.do_something
  all.each do |question|
    #do stuff
  end
end

questions = Question.pick_random.load
User.all.each { |user| questions.do_something_for(user) }
```

The problem is : This load the questions every time the method is called...
It's pretty slow, obviously. Is there any method to not reload the query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could memoize the results:

```
def self.do_something
  @do_something ||= begin
    all.each do |question|
      #do stuff
    end
  end
end
```

Then, the query (and the computation) will only be performed the first time you call the method. The next time, it will just return `@do_something`

Comment: @exalia Would you mind marking my result as correct? SO award points for correct answers :)